# How to get all the occurrence of each distinct value including its quantities in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a SQL table that looks like this:

```
item_price | discount | quantity
  2000.00  | 360.00 | 02
  2000.00 | 360.00 | 01
  1589.00 | 250.00  | 01
```

How would I get all the occurrence of each item_prices but exclude discounts (include ones that multiple quantities)? for example: for item_price '2000.00', I will get 3 for its occurrence.

I have:

```
select count(item_price) * quantity as occurrence from order_items group by 1;
```

But it only returns 2 for item_price '2000.00'

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Group by item_price, count by item_price and value of (qty*item_price) and average discount:

```
select
       item_price
     , count(*)          as occurrence 
     , sum(item_price * quantity) as value_of
     , avg(discount)              as avg_discount
from order_items 
group by
       item_price
;
```

Comment: sorry, I'm trying to create a frequency distribution table of order items. For example, The item price of $200 from the table have 3 occurrences, but my query only returns 2

Comment: What query? What data? I can see neither.  The query  i provided above would return a count of 3 if it found 3 rows of the same price. "our query may be different somehow or your data may be different to you expectations.

Comment: alright, let me try to explain again. Item_price of $200 has 3 orders (from the table above). The query 'select count (*) or count (item_price) only return '2 orders' for item_price of $200. My question is how to write a query that returns a count of same price including its quantity?

Comment: You really need to provide more sample data showing the 3 rows you are trying to describe. No number of words will substitute for data. ADD this into your question. Don't try using comments for this.  Once you provide sample data also provide "the expected result".